# Classes And Events

Tags: javascript

How can I add an event to an HTML Class after I define it using document.getElementByClassName?

So I have this `let pledgeHeader = document.getElementsByClassName("pledge-header");`

And when I try to add an event to it `pledgeHeader.onclick = function(){this.style.display = "none"}` it doesn't do anything. How can I make events work with classes?

Comment: pledgeHeader[0].onclick

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements, not just one element. You can do a `forEach` on the result and add the handler that way:

```js
let pledgeHeader = document.getElementsByClassName("pledge-header");

pledgeHeader.forEach(el => {
    el.onclick = function(){this.style.display = "none"}
}
```

Or, if you know you only have one element with that class, you can just do `pledgeHeader[0].onclick = ...`. Basically what you already have, but with `[0]` to access the first element in the array.

**Update**

If you know you'll only ever have one "pledgeHeader" why not give that element and `id="pledgeHeader"`, then change your code to `let pledgeHeader = document.getElementById("pledgeHeader")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the elements and an an event listener to each one. You should use `document.querySelectorAll`, though, unless you need a live `HTMLCollection`.

```
for(const el of document.querySelectorAll(".pledge-header")){
   el.addEventListener('click', function(e){
      this.style.display = 'none';
   });
}
```

If there is only one element or you only want the first element, you can directly use `document.querySelector`.

```
document.querySelector('.pledge-header').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    this.style.display = 'none';
});
```